# jquery get selected checkbox row and pass it in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using jquery function to get the selected checkbox row from the table and it worked fine after i get that data i need to pass it in ajax where i get an error myData is undefined and my code is

```
 $("#user-table-form").on('submit', function(e){
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var method = $(this).attr('method');
        usertable.$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
          var myData = $(this).parent().siblings().eq(2).text();
         alert(myData);
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: myData,
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Promocode added successfully");
                //window.location.href = "{{ route('admin.promocode')}}";
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                //console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
   });
```

when i run my browser console show this error

```
user?userTable_length=10:347 Uncaught ReferenceError: myData is not defined
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (user?userTable_length=10:347)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Where i need to define that variable please any one help me

Comment: move `var myData` outside `.each()`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
usertable.$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
  var myData = $(this).parent().siblings().eq(2).text();
  alert(myData);
});
```

move `var myData` outside of loop like:

```
var myData = [];
usertable.$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
  myData.push($(this).parent().siblings().eq(2).text());
});
alert(myData);
```

Comment: Now tthat error went but it doesnot goes to ajax success function

Comment: It shows the full data `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<title>Products</title>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\" />\n<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\" />\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://birdys.app/admin-assets/css/bootstrap.min.css\" />\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://birdys.app/admin-assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css\" />\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://birdys.app/admin-assets/css/fullcalendar.css`

Comment: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"<html>\r\n<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.11.9</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n","status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}